# Isometric map vs symmetry transformation in a finite-dimensional Hilbert space

Tags: geometry, hilbert-spaces, symmetry, isometry

For a given finite-dimensional complex Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ with the inner product $\langle \cdot | \cdot\rangle$, a map $f: \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ is said to be an isometric map if
$$
||f(x) - f(y)|| = ||x-y||, \forall x,y \in {\cal H}.
$$
Besides, we assume that $f(0)=0$.

A map $g: \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ is said to be a symmetry transformation if
$$
|\langle \overline{g(x)}|\overline{g(y)}\rangle | = |\langle \bar{x}|\bar{y}\rangle|, \forall x,y \in {\cal H},
$$
where
$\bar{x}$ is the unit vector which share the same direction as $x$, etc.

According to [Wigner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_theorem), every symmetry transformation is either an unitary or anti-unitary. Hence, symmetry transformation is always an isometric map.

**Then the question is**,

> Is every isometric map a symmetry transformation in a finite-dimensional complex Hilbert space?

This is true indeed if ${\cal H}$ is a real Hilbert space.

There are many similar questions in this forum, none of them has a proper answer to this question. For example:

1. [$f$ an isometry from a hilbert space $H$ to itself such that $f(0)=0$ then $f$ linear.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/121046/91439)
2. [How to find all isometries of Hilbert space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/890415/91439)
3. [Symmetry vs isometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3342077/91439)
4. [Mazur-Ulam-like theorem for complex Hilbert spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3482576)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true. Here is an example.

Let's consider a two-dimensional Hilbert space ${\cal H}_2$ and the map $f$:
$$
f: (a+bi,c+di) \to (a+bi,c-di).
$$
It's easy to verify that $f$ is an isomorphism. Meanwhile, $f$ is not a symmetry transformation since
$$
\langle f((1+i,1+i))|f((1-i,1-i))\rangle = \langle (1+i,1-i)|(1-i,1+i) \rangle = 0.
$$
$$
\langle (1+i,1+i)|(1-i,1-i) \rangle = 4i.
$$